# как работать с GeoJson?

Tags: android, kotlin, geojson

Хотела бы узнать как импортировать данные GeoJSON из сервера.
https://waadsu.com/api/russia.geo.json

Comment: не нужно использовать метку android-studio в вопросах не связанных с IDE

Comment: Статические данные можно скачать, положить в ресурсы приложения, читать оттуда когда надо.